# SubQuery taking too long in postgreSQL Server

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that is taking a lot to time to execute. I am not sure how do i reduce this. Not only time this query also takes PSQL to high CPU usage.

I have to select a single column `sip_username` as diffrent names on diffrent conditions. Due to that requirement I have create subqueries,

The Query is :

```sql
SELECT   sip_username,
         product_code,
         display_name as dname,
         user_id as uid,
         location_id,
         tenant_id,
         (
           SELECT sip_username
           FROM   admin_users_product
           WHERE  (sip_username = A.sip_username)  AND    
                  (product_code = 'bizfms')
         ) AS bizfms_username,
         (
           SELECT sip_username
           FROM admin_users_product
           WHERE (sip_username = A.sip_username) AND
                 (product_code = 'mlc')
                 ) AS mlc_username,
         (
           SELECT sip_username
           FROM admin_users_product
           WHERE (sip_username = A.sip_username) AND
                 (product_code = 'bizrtm')
         ) AS bizrtm_username
FROM     admin_users_product AS A
WHERE    A.location_id = 18
```

What should i change to make this faster ?

Comment: Please remove tag: `sql-server`.

Comment: Please execute the query with prefix `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) ` and add the output to your question. It will help to show you how to solve similar issues yourself in the future.

Comment: What is the primary key of the table `admin_users_product`? Will the condition `a.location_id = 18` return multiple rows with different `product_code` and `sip_username` values?

Comment: Could you post sample data and expected output for them? It would be much easier to help you.

Comment: Your sub-queries don't make sense. The condition to return the row is `sip_username = A.sip_username` so the sip_username returned for each sub-query will be identical to the one in `a.sip_username` - which you already have. So I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with the sub-queries. It looks like you can easily just remove them

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name primary key is id and a.location=18 will return multiple rows with diffrent product code

Comment: But the display of the `sip_username` doesn't really make sense then, as that will always be the same username as the one shown in the "main" select list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
SELECT sip_username,
   product_code,
   display_name as dname,
   user_id      as uid,
   location_id,
   tenant_id,
   (CASE product_code
        WHEN 'bizfms' THEN
            sip_username
        ELSE Null
       END)     AS bizfms_username,
   (CASE product_code
        WHEN 'mlc' THEN
            sip_username
        ELSE Null
       END)     AS mlc_username,
   (CASE product_code
        WHEN 'bizrtm' THEN
            sip_username
        ELSE Null
       END)     AS bizrtm_username
  FROM admin_users_product AS A
  WHERE A.location_id = 18
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create index on some column

1. Create index on admin_users_product table on location_id and sip_username columns
2. Create index on admin_users_product table on sip_username and product_code columns

and then you query run more faster...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.
Case do not exists index, you need to create as mencioned per Mirnamiq Abdullayev.

```
SELECT   sip_username,
         product_code,
         display_name as dname,
         user_id as uid,
         location_id,
         tenant_id,
         B.sip_username bizfms_username,
         C.sip_username mlc_username,
         D.sip_username bizrtm_username,
FROM      admin_users_product AS A
left join admin_users_product B
    on A.sip_username = B.sip_username and B.product_code = 'bizfms'
left join admin_users_product C
    on A.sip_username = C.sip_username and C.product_code = 'mlc'
left join admin_users_product D
    on A.sip_username = D.sip_username and D.product_code = 'bizrtm'
WHERE
    A.location_id = 18;
```